# Download PHP table and put into data frame or matrix

Tags: php, r

I want to put the contents of this PHP table into a data frame using R.

URL:  http://ehshoes.robertjromano.com/view.php

```
library(XML)
u <- "http://ehshoes.robertjromano.com/view.php"
tables <- readHTMLTable(u)
tmp <- tables[[1]]      ##this gets rid of " $`NULL`" on first line
```

tmp is now a list containing the data.

How would I put the contents of tmp into a data frame? I really just need to put the 2nd, 4th and 6th columns into a dataframe.

FYI, this data will be used by a web app I have running on Shiny R. Each time the website is loaded, the data set will be obtained from the URL above, and the data will be plotted. Right now its getting the data from a google doc. This is the app that connects to google docs: https://jeise.shinyapps.io/ehShoes/

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readHTMLTable` returns a data frame, so all you need to do is subset to your desired columns and convert to the correct data types:

```
library(XML)
u <- "http://ehshoes.robertjromano.com/view.php"
dat <- readHTMLTable(u, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[[1]][,c(2, 4, 6)]
names(dat) <- c("Latitude", "Longitude", "Time")
dat$Latitude <- as.numeric(dat$Latitude)
dat$Longitude <- as.numeric(dat$Longitude)
dat$Time <- strptime(dat$Time, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 47 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ Latitude : num  26 26 26 25.8 25.8 ...
#  $ Longitude: num  -80.3 -80.3 -80.3 -80.4 -80.4 ...
#  $ Time     : POSIXlt, format: "2014-04-12 20:35:21" "2014-04-12 20:34:58" "2014-04-12 20:34:35" ...
```

You'll note that I added `header=FALSE`, which ensures that you're not getting the first row of data as the header of your data frame, as well as `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, which makes manipulation of the character text being read in a bit easier.